# Are sequence containers not a subset of general containers?

Tags: c++, stl

`stack` does not have an `iterator`-member-type, and therefore does not meet the general container requirements: `[container.requirements.general]`.

But in `[container.adaptors.general]`

> The headers `<queue>` and `<stack>` define the container adaptors `queue`, `priority_queue`, and `stack`. These
>   container adaptors meet the requirements for sequence containers.

Are sequence containers not a subset of general containers?

Comment: seems like you have found a defect

Comment: `Table 100 — Sequence container requirements (in addition to container)`

Comment: Seeing how this seems not to be a well known problem (0 answers in one hour), I, exceptionally, cross posted this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c++/ovDXZtVR4qY

Comment: The standard provides following information "The library also provides container adaptors that make it easy to construct
abstract data types, such as stacks or queues, out of the basic sequence container kinds (or out of other
kinds of sequence containers that the user might define)." So in general case stack not exactly container. It is ADT with specific semantical  interface.

Comment: @Sergey: Yes, but the standard also says `The headers and define the container adaptors queue, priority_queue, and stack. These container adaptors meet the requirements for sequence containers.`

Comment: C++ active issues list, with contact email address. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html. I'm not sure what the proper protocol is though, whether it's correct to use that address or comp.lang.c++. Unless there's something subtle in the language that we're all missing, or it's already fixed in the ISO standard, I think this is pretty clearly a defect.

Comment: ... the defect being that it shouldn't say they're sequence containers, I mean.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Good point with link. Just contacted Mr. Miller of EDG to ask for how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a defect ( http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-active.html#2194 ):

> Since sequence containers is a subset of general containers, this imposes requirements on the container adaptors that are not satisfied. [...] 
>   As the NB comment noticed, the adaptors really are not sequences nor containers, so this wording needs to be fixed. The most simple way to realize that is to strike the offending sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Sequence containers are a subset of general containers.

However, sequence adaptors don't meet the requirements specific to sequence containers (no `insert` member functions), and as you've noticed don't meet the general container requirements either. I don't think `[container.adaptors.general]` should say they do, but it does say that in the C++11 drafts I have.